# Access Denied System Volume Information

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, filesystems

I'm listing all files in a USB device and doing natural search like code below.My problem is when i try to get all folders in a usb device im getting System Volume Information folder too and when i try to access im getting access denied error.

Actually i try "try catch" but this time it's brings empty list.

By the way im getting this error on a NFTS file system USB Device.FAT32 works fine.

```
Declare Unicode Function StrCmpLogicalW Lib "shlwapi.dll" (ByVal s1 As String, ByVal s2 As String) As Int32
Private Function CompareFiles(x As String, y As String) As Integer
    Return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y)
End Function
For Each driver As DriveInfo In DriveInfo.GetDrives()
        If driver.IsReady And driver.DriveType = DriveType.Removable Then

            Dim ext = {"*.zip"}

            Dim rootFiles() As String = ext.SelectMany(Function(f) Directory.GetFiles(driver.RootDirectory.ToString, f, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)).OrderBy(Function(f) f).ToArray()
            Array.Sort(rootFiles, New Comparison(Of String)(AddressOf CompareFiles))
            'Next line gets System Volume Information
            Dim otherFiles = ext.SelectMany(Function(f) Directory.GetFiles(driver.RootDirectory.ToString, f, SearchOption.AllDirectories)).OrderBy(Function(f) f).ToArray()
            Array.Sort(otherFiles, New Comparison(Of String)(AddressOf CompareFiles))
            ComBoxUsb.Items.Clear()

            For Each model In rootFiles.Union(otherFiles)
                ComBoxUsb.Items.Add(model)
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: From Windows explorer that folder is hidden by default so you may need to change that property.

Comment: You, usually have to options: 1) Have a secondary method that catches the exception, 2) have a secondary method (or a lambda) that tests the current Directory access level - `Directory.GetAccessControl().GetAccessRules()` - agaist the current user - `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` - to verify whether the user has a `SecurityIdentifier ` that is included in any of the `AuthorizationRule` collection `IdentityReference`s. Many prefer the first solution.